# Link redirection issue while adding a custom tab on customer Dashboard in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to add the custom link on customer dashboard in magento 2.

I have added

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="demo-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/controller/action</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Demo Link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

on my module.Actually i have followed http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-add-link-in-my-account-navigation-panel/ . I changed the path to my module controller.Till here it is working good.

But there are two things that i couldn't achieve:

one is When i click on that tab it is redirecting to me to the entirely new page.The page that was defined on my layout's xml file. so I added the code of updating the handle of customer account. see my xml file.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">         
            <block class="Custom\Addprofile\Block\Index\Index" name="index.index" template="Custom_Addprofile::index/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is still not working as expected. The template should load aside of the left navigation links on the account dashboard.

Am I missing some thing here?

- Also Another thing i was trying achieve is i want to display that custom tab to particular customer group only. Is there any easy way of achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `layout="1column"` to `layout="2columns-left"` in your custom layout file.

it should be

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">         
            <block class="Custom\Addprofile\Block\Index\Index" name="index.index" template="Custom_Addprofile::index/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Look for Reference:** `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

**update**

```
protected $_customersession;
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customersession)
{

        $this->_customersession=$customersession
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    if($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn())
    {
        echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();  // get Customer Group Id
    }
}
```

you can add the above logic in block or helper and make decision to show or not by overriding corresponding update_handle phtml.

Comment: Thanks bibal it worked. have you got any idea of showing that tab to customer of particular customer group only?

Comment: see my updated answer. if you can't get, can you please raise new question with your stuff  I will elaborate.

Comment: sure bilal. here is my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142032/show-the-added-custom-tab-on-customer-dashboard-to-particular-customer-group-onl