# Show the added custom tab on customer dashboard to particular customer group only Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have added the custom tab on the customer dashboard using the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <!-- <update handle="customer_account_navigation"/> -->

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="demo-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">addprofile/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Demo Link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now what I want is I want to show this tab to only a particular customer group. As the link was added through the XML file and when I checked the **navigation.phtml** it is rendering all the links using

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
```

So I wasn't able to add some condition there.

can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: [Here is the full version of @Bilal Usean answer. click here for solution.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237748/63460)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you get an idea from this, I have not tested. I have tried like remove that block programatically when customer group id is not match with our expectation, .

```
protected $_customersession;
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customersession)
{
  $this->_customersession=$customersession
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    if($this->_customersession->isLoggedIn())
    {
        $cgid=$customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();  // get Customer Group Id
        if($cgid!="yourExpectedId")
        {
            $layout = $this->getLayout();
            $block = $layout->getBlock('demo-link'); // block name
            $layout->unsetElement('demo-link'); //remove block
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bilal thanks for the answer but i am confused on implementing it.where should i add this code as the tab is added from layout. Also i didn't find the template for customer_account

Comment: in layout you can't find customer group for add tab, as I know the only possibilities to check from controller so you should need to apply this logic in your custom controller execute method.

Comment: How is that going to work coz i want to hide this tab for particular customer group but controller of my module is only executed when someone click this link

Comment: oh you right! in your case you need to override and try this logic in `app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Index.php`

Comment: Hi bilal i tried it above code. The line with $layout = $this->getLayout(); is giving the error of unable to handle the request. can you suggest what could possibly go wrong.

Comment: it is happen suddenly or from the beginning? refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87632/36463

Comment: also refer this for how to get layout object http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88847/36463